# How to access to url of my pod tomcat deployed on kubernetes

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes, devops

I had deploy a tomcat on kubernetes and when I run this command : `kubectl describe svc dev-tomcat` I have this :

```
Name:              dev-tomcat
Namespace:         dev
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=dev-tomcat
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.50.54.10
Port:              tomcat  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.115.122.114:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

How can I access to tomcat now ? when I try to run this on my browser nothing appears :

```
http://10.115.122.114:8080
```

Comment: Is it your local kubernetes installation i.e. something like **Minikube** set up on your PC or laptop ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `IP` from the output, try `10.50.54.10:8080`

Update:

for minikube, you need to use `NodePort`

I did following

```
    kubectl create deployment tomcatinfra --image=saravak/tomcat8
     
    kubectl expose deployment tomcatinfra --port=8080 --target-port=8080 --type NodePort
     
    kubectl get svc

    minikube service tomcatinfra
```

Comment: I have nothing too... I don't understand why

Comment: for minikube you cant use clusterIP, you need to use NodePort

Answer (score 0):

Since the service only has a ClusterIP, You can port-forward to the service from your machine to access it

`kubectl port-forward svc/dev-tomcat 8080`

and then access localhost:8080 from your browser